# Braintree: Recurring payment status report

Tags: braintree

How does the information about recurring payment failure/success reach me?

Do I have to ping it myself or does BT send the response?

If it is the first case then when exactly should I check that? E.g when billing date is 1st August, then at what time it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).

You can set up [`webhooks`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/overview) that notify you when the status of your [`subscriptions`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/subscription/ruby) change. These webhooks are set up in the Braintree Control Panel and send POST requests to your server endpoints when needed.